# Use one system hard disk alternately for two identical PCs

Tags: ssd, operating-systems

I use two identical PCs in the home office and in the "real" office. I have been synchronizing the two data HDDs in the two PCs for years using a synchronization program via Internet.

However, such synchronization is not possible for the system SSD on which Windows and programs are installed. So I'm thinking of physically moving the C-SSD back and forth between the two computers using a [front-mount removable drive](https://www.icydock.com/goods.php?id=234):

[image]

Has anyone done this before?

As I expect difficulties with Windows activation and with the activation/licensing of installed programs, is there a way to avoid these?

Comment: Why not just sync the data and documents you need. That is a common way to handle this issue.

Comment: As I'm constantly changing settings and installing programs, I'd like to do this only once for the two identical machines that I use. I see that I should reword my question into how to work around activation problems.

Comment: Not posting this as answer, since it is not precisely what you asked. But you can use three windows installations (or 2x whatever OS + 1x Windows) if you use a VM and carry that around. And you could even sync the whole VM at shut down to a reachable location. So no more forgetting to carry the drive from onbe place to another.

Comment: Ore even run the windows setup somewhere remote. Cloud is popular, but as long as you have decent internet connection in one location you could use one single windows setup and a slave computer to RDP from.

Answer (score 2):

Just because they *look* identical does not mean they truly are.

Windows relies on some unknown mixture of hardware IDs and serial numbers in order to validate your product licence. If those IDs suddenly change, as they would when moving a hard drive from one machine to another, then windows will deactivate itself. If both machines have valid licences then they *should* reactivate. The problem is though that we don't know what limits there truly are on reactivations.

It could be three per month, or five per year. From what I know "minor" changes to things like memory and hard drives do not actually deactivate the licence, but it could be that it still ends up generating a new hardware ID that is linked to the old one.

Swapping a hard drive between machines though *would* be an entirely different hardware ID and would not work.

While you can [`sysprep`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation) a Windows installation to allow you to clone it between machines, it is not intended to be used for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should only carry my third SSD where I install all programs back and forth, and additionally bend my C:\Users\UserName folder to that drive as well using a junction. This way, only the settings in the registry would not be synchronized.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion about registry syncing here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/328017/syncing-windows-registry-between-several-computers

Comment: The problem there is that you want to be incredibly selective about syncing the registry, as just copying the entire thing is the same as cloning the original computer and will break activation or worse. What you propose for the users directory might work, but I would be incredibly wary of doing it for the system registry. I would personally just set up a central backup of program installers to set up on the second machine and use portable apps wherever possible. For two "identical" machines Windows is not the OS I would use, you might find Linux works better in this regard.

Comment: Thanks. I just saw that according to experience, a junction should not be used anymore these days for relocating the user folder but instead this approach: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html

Comment: If you were to have a removable drive for your user profiles you would also want to disable windows fast startup and hibernation on both machines, and make sure that you **always** shut down one machine before moving to the other. Otherwise the drive may not be finished being properly written to when you move them.

Comment: I just noticed that the user-specific part of the registry (Ntuser.dat) is stored in the user folder. If I put the user folder on the removable disk with the installed programs, and move this disk back and forth between the two computers, then I have almost all possible settings synchronized on both computers, don't I?

Comment: Partly. User settings for programs, yes. Per-user file associations, yes. Any settings that are stored system wide such as installer/uninstaller stuff, links and so on would not be in the per-user profile.

Answer (score 0):

OK so now I went for using dedicated SSDs for the system drives on each of the two machines.

However, additionally to having all programs installed on a second SSD with drive letter F, I moved the C:\Users folder also to drive F, namely to F:\Users using [this method](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html).

Now I can swap that second SSD with all programs, user files (and data btw.) between the two PCs, and have everything (data, programs, and all settings) perfectly syncronized all the time.